# Is exist this type of database? (like time-series db, can get specific time point data...)

Tags: sql, database, time-series

Suppose I have data structure like below...

USER_KEY is USER's Unique Key
STATUS, 1 is Online, 0 is Offline
UPDATED_DATE is Status last updated date

```
USER_KEY | STATUS |     UPDATED_DATE
----------------------------------------
    1    |    1   | 2017-06-19 00:01:00
    2    |    1   | 2017-06-19 00:01:01
    3    |    1   | 2017-06-19 00:01:02
    4    |    1   | 2017-06-19 00:01:02
    1    |    0   | 2017-06-19 05:42:06
```

and I wanna get specific time point data.

when I select '`2017-06-19 04:00:00`'
live user count is `4` 
and live user is `{1,2,3,4}`

and when i select `'2017-06-19 11:00:00'`,
live user count is `3`
and live user is `{2,3,4}`
because user 1 went to offline at 5:42 AM.

and I wanna get specific time point data.
I'm saving user status data every hour until now.
this data is too big and inefficient.
is exist database can save efficiently this type of data?

Surely, can save just count number everytime, but I need not only count, but also all user's key.

Comment: Edit your question and tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: @GordonLinoff  I'm using SQL Server but this is not about sql server.

Comment: how is this question not about sql server. The sql syntax is different on each database

Comment: Just save user status every hour there is really no other way to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for the last status for each user before a given point in time.  In SQL Server, you can use window functions:

```
select count(*)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by user_key order by updated_date desc) as seqnum
      from t
      where updated_date < @datetime
     ) t
where seqnum = 1 and status = 1;
```

You can say `select *` if you want the list of users.

I don't know what you mean by "type of database".  You can readily do this in standard SQL.

Comment: thank you for answer. 'type of database' mean another db like influxdb, postgresql,etc... sorry for choosing vagueness word.